# Name-lookup ambiguity inconsistency

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, using-directives, name-lookup

I'm trying to understand why this program does not give an name-lookup ambiguity for i:

```
namespace X { int i = 1; }

namespace Q {    
    namespace P {        
        int i = 2;
        using namespace X;
    }

    using namespace P;

    int l = i;
}

int main() {}
```

If we modify it like this we get a name-lookup ambiguity:

```
namespace X { int i = 1; }

namespace P {        
    int i = 2;
    using namespace X;
}

using namespace P;

int l = i;

int main() {}
```

The only change I made here is to remove the namespace Q and place it's content in the global namespace instead.

I have tried with 3 different compilers:

- GCC and Clang with http://melpon.org/wandbox
- visual c++ with http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

The all give the results stated in this email, and i'm trying to find out why.

Can anyone explain the behaviour in terms of the c++ standard? I fail to understand it.

Comment: Hasn't this just been answered on std-discussion? https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/7K4p4FCdq6o/9bDtklvVzZgJ

Comment: On second thought, this is a valid question on SO, but probably a duplicate.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10741428/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first program used variable `i` is defined in namespace P because the using directive

```
using namespace X;
```

places declarations of X in the global namespace (the common namepsace for X and P). Thus the declaration of `i` in P (more precisely in Q due to another using directive) hides the declaration of `X::i` in the global namespace.

From the C++ Standard (3.4.1 Unqualified name lookup)

> 2 The declarations from the namespace nominated by a using-directive
>   become visible in a namespace enclosing the using-directive; see
>   7.3.4.

So we have for the first program

```
namespace X { int i = 1; }

namespace Q {    
    namespace P {        
        int i = 2;
        using namespace X; // 1
    }

    using namespace P; // 2

    int l = i;
}
```

that the enclosing namespace for using directive #1 is the global namespace and the enclosing namespace for using directive #2 is the namepsace Q.

In the second program the both definitions of `i` are placed in the global namespace due to these two using directives

```
//...
using namespace X;
//...
using namespace P;
```